# I cant run react native app.Error: When running doctor Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android - Versions found: N/A

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

When i am running the npm - Required to install NPM dependencies. It give me this output:

Common
✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
✓ npm - Required to install NPM dependencies

Android
✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

- Versions found: N/A
- Version supported: 33.0.0
  ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mMNL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoGtS.png)

I add cmdline_tools, sdk, platform-tools and tools to the path. But these not fixed the problem.
Can anyone know another solution for it. I add to the releated path images.